# I want to realize transaction Match .can I use chronicle in it?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I want to realize transaction Match .can I use chronicle in it ? and How to use it ?

thanks. I am writing log with it.but some error happend like :

## Problematic frame:

## J 927 C2 net.openhft.chronicle.wire.BinaryWire.copyOne(Lnet/openhft/chronicle/wire/WireOut;)V (751 bytes) @ 0x000000011291e0d4 [0x000000011291ce20+0x12b4]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000797b8ba58 is an oop
[C
 - klass: {type array char}
 - length: 76
RBX=0x0000000000c00000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000797b8ba40 is an oop
java.lang.StringBuilder
 - klass: 'java/lang/StringBuilder'
RSP=0x000070000752b3a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9cc7806800
RBP=0x00000000f2f7174b is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000c00055 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000797b75cf8 is an oop
net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedBytes
 - klass: 'net/openhft/chronicle/bytes/MappedBytes'
R9 =0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000001123cffff is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000f2f71748 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000001123cffff is an unknown value
R14=0x00000000f2f71637 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f9cc7806800 is a thread.
it is information in hs_err_pid73671.log .is there some bug with my code?

Comment: Can you give some more information here. Describe some more information about the system you are using. It isn't clear from your question what platform you're even using. Also, adding Tags to your question can help funnel it to the right people who know and understand the underlying technologies

Comment: I need a queue to restore transaction for match. and I can use chronicle to persist data to files as log.but I want to know what else i can do by that?

Comment: You can use chronicle queue to feed transactions to a matching engine. Chronicle doesn't consume messages on read so they can be replayed as many times as you need.